# Returning only last item and splitting into columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having a couple of issues - I seem to be only returning the last item on this list. Can someone help me here please? I also want to split the df into columns filtering all of the postcodes into one column. Not sure where to start with this. Help much appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pandas as pd

URL = "https://www.matki.co.uk/matki-dealers/"

page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find(class_="dealer-overview") 
company_elements = results.find_all("article")

for company_element in company_elements:

company_info = company_element.getText(separator=u', ').replace('Find out more »', '')

print (company_info)

data = {company_info}

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df.shape

df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you need to replace the loop with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'info': [e.getText(separator=u', ')
                             .replace('Find out more »', '')
                            for e in company_elements]})
```

output:

```
                                                  info
0    ESP Bathrooms & Interiors, Queens Retail Park,...
1    Paul Scarr & Son Ltd, Supreme Centre, Haws Hil...
2    Stonebridge Interiors, 19 Main Street, Pontela...
3    Bathe Distinctive Bathrooms, 55 Pottery Road, ...
4    Draw A Bath Ltd, 68 Telegraph Road, Heswall, W...
..                                                 ...
346  Warren Keys, Unit B Carrs Lane, Tromode, Dougl...
347  Haldane Fisher, Isle of Man Business Park, Coo...
348  David Scott (Agencies) Ltd, Supreme Centre, 11...
349  Ballycastle Homecare Ltd, 2 The Diamond, Bally...
350  Beggs & Partners, Great Patrick Street, Belfas...

[351 rows x 1 columns]
```